# Highlight dates within next week

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want a formula that highlight the dates that within next week.

[image: photo]

I know how to highlight within the *current week*, with this formula:

```
=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),3)=$F6-WEEKDAY($F6,3)
```

(shown in the red highlight)

and I also know how to highlight within the *7 days after 7 days from today*, with this formula:

```
=AND($F6-TODAY()>=7,$F6-TODAY()<=13)
```

(shown in the green highlight)

but what about highlighting all dates within next week, regardless being synchronous with today?

Notice that the green highlight does not cover next Monday as the 7 days are formulated to move synchronously with today date not limited to be within next week.

Comment: Clarification: Do you want the green highlight to start 7 days after the first red-highlighted date?

Comment: No, I want the green highlight to be in any dates that are located within next week that start from next Monday to Sunday (only limited by the 7 days of the next week, not after not before)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following formula in the Conditional Formatting (Use Formula to determine which cells to format and choose the formatting you want:

`=AND(F6>=TODAY()+7-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2),F6<=TODAY()+13-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2))`

F6 is the date you want to format
I started the week with Monday (I used 2 for weekday to determine which day is today())